# ValueError: shapes (2,210) and (2,210) not aligned: 210 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Tags: arrays, scipy, curve-fitting, shapes, scipy-optimize

I want to fit an intensity distribution function to 2D image data using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` and can't locate the error in my code:

```py
# Define doughnut beam intensity distribution function
def doughnut(x, y, x0, y0, A, FWHM):
    '''2D intensity distribution function of doughnut beams (DOI: 10.1126/science.aak9913,
    https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2016/12/21/science.aak9913.DC1/Balzarotti_SM.pdf).

    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : float
        X and Y coordinates, orthogonal to beam axis
    x0 : float
        X offset
    y0 : float
        Y offset
    A : float
        Peak intensity
    FWHM : float
        Full width at half maximum
    '''
    return A*np.exp(1)*4*np.log(2)*(np.dot(x+x0,x+x0) + np.dot(y+y0,y+y0))/FWHM**2*np.exp(-4*np.log(2)*(np.dot(x+x0,x+x0) + np.dot(y+y0,y+y0))/FWHM**2)

# Read image file names
pathname = '/home/user/doughnut_beam/'
filenameList = [filename for filename in os.listdir(pathname)
                if filename.endswith('.tif')]

# Open image files, fit doughnut beam intensity distribution function
for filename in filenameList:
    img = Image.open(pathname + filename)

    X, Y = img.size
    xRange = np.arange(1, X+1)
    yRange = np.arange(1, Y+1)
    xGrid, yGrid = np.meshgrid(xRange, yRange)
    xyGrid = np.vstack((xGrid.ravel(), yGrid.ravel()))    # scipy.optimize.curve_fit requires 2xN-array 

    imgArray = np.array(img)
    imgArrayFlat = imgArray.ravel()    # Flatten 2D pixel data into 1D array for scipy.optimize.curve_fit
    
    params_opt, params_cov = curve_fit(doughnut, xyGrid, imgArrayFlat)
```

This is the output from Jupyter Notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-eaa3ebdb6469> in <module>()
     17     imgArrayFlat = imgArray.ravel()    # Flatten 2D pixel data into 1D array for scipy.optimize.curve_fit
     18 
---> 19     params_opt, params_cov = curve_fit(doughnut, xyGrid, imgArrayFlat)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    749         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    750         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 751         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    752         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    753         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    381     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    382         args = (args,)
--> 383     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    384     m = shape[0]
    385     if n > m:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     25 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     26                 output_shape=None):
---> 27     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     28     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     29         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    461     if transform is None:
    462         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 463             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    464     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    465         def func_wrapped(params):

<ipython-input-43-3e0adae6fbe0> in doughnut(x, y, x0, y0, A, FWHM)
     17         Full width at half maximum
     18     '''
---> 19     return A*np.exp(1)*4*np.log(2)*(np.dot(x+x0,x+x0) + np.dot(y+y0,y+y0))/FWHM**2*np.exp(-4*np.log(2)*(np.dot(x+x0,x+x0) + np.dot(y+y0,y+y0))/FWHM**2)

ValueError: shapes (2,210) and (2,210) not aligned: 210 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

**UPDATE**: For some reason, using `numpy.dot` to square the (offset) variables `x+x0` and `y+y0` in the function definition does not work. Simply changing to the `**` operator results in the correct plot:

```
# UPDATED: Define doughnut beam intensity distribution function
def doughnut(x, y, x0, y0, A, FWHM):
    '''2D intensity distribution function of doughnut beams (DOI: 10.1126/science.aak9913,
    https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2016/12/21/science.aak9913.DC1/Balzarotti_SM.pdf).

    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : float
        X and Y coordinates, orthogonal to beam axis
    x0 : float
        X offset
    y0 : float
        Y offset
    A : float
        Peak intensity
    FWHM : float
        Full width at half maximum
    '''
    return A*np.exp(1)*4*np.log(2)*((x+x0)**2 + (y+y0)**2)/FWHM**2*np.exp(-4*np.log(2)*((x+x0)**2 + (y+y0)**2)/FWHM**2)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data
X = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = doughnut(X, Y, x0=0, y0=0, A=1.5, FWHM=7)

# Plot the surface
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

=> [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poPuD.png)

**BUT**: Now I'm getting a new error when trying to fit the data:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-eaa3ebdb6469> in <module>()
     17     imgArrayFlat = imgArray.ravel()    # Flatten 2D pixel data into 1D array for scipy.optimize.curve_fit
     18 
---> 19     params_opt, params_cov = curve_fit(doughnut, xyGrid, imgArrayFlat)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    749         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    750         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 751         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    752         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    753         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    384     m = shape[0]
    385     if n > m:
--> 386         raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
    387     if epsfcn is None:
    388         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

TypeError: Improper input: N=5 must not exceed M=2
```

Comment: Looks like something’s wrong with your `donut` function, can you post an example of running that function outside of `curve_fit` that doesn’t raise an exception?

Comment: @DavidHoffman: You were right, the function contained an error, although I do not understand it: I used `numpy.dot` to square `x+x0` and `y+y0`, but this gives in a wrong plot. Simply using `(x+x0)**2` and `(y+y0)` results in the correct plot. **BUT**: Now I'm getting a new error...I have updated the question!

Comment: The error still looks the same, did you update that part too? For your `donut` function you need to pass in the independent variables (`y` and `x`) as a _single_ argument. I’ve passed it as a tuple which I then unpack in the function.

Comment: The `donut` function also needs to return a 1D array.

Comment: @DavidHoffman: Actually, the function returns a 2D array (looking at `print(Z)`), is this wrong? I mean, the plot looks fine...

Comment: And what do you mean by passing `x` and `y` as a "single argument"? You mean as `(x, y)`?

Comment: I'm confused by the data structure that `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` requires as input (*raveled* Z-values, X/Y values from a *raveled 2xM meshgrid array*???). From a mathematical POV, the function takes six *scalars* `x`, `x0`, `y`, `y0`, `A`, and `FWHM` as input (in fact, the original definition uses polar coordinates with `r = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)`) - the image data, however, is present in the form of *arrays* (which is why I originally used `numpy.dot` instead of `**` for the squared variables) - but then the fit algorithm takes *raveled arrays*. This is too much overhead/not very pythonic IMHO

Comment: The `curve_fit` interface isn’t intuitive for functions of more than one dimension. In this case, both your function return and you dependent variables need to be 1 dimensional arrays. The independent variable can be anything, as long as it’s passed as a single variable.

Comment: @DavidHoffman: How can I pass `x` and `y` as a single variable?

Comment: I made an answer, take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Take a look at the `for_fitting` function to see how you can package everything in a way `curve_fit` will accept.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def doughnut(y, x, y0, x0, A, FWHM):
    """2D intensity distribution function of doughnut beams (DOI: 10.1126/science.aak9913,
    https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2016/12/21/science.aak9913.DC1/Balzarotti_SM.pdf).

    Parameters
    ----------
    y, x : float
        X and Y coordinates, orthogonal to beam axis
    y0 : float
        Y offset
    x0 : float
        X offset
    A : float
        Peak intensity
    FWHM : float
        Full width at half maximum
    """
    return (
        A
        * np.e
        * 4
        * np.log(2)
        * ((x + x0) ** 2 + (y + y0) ** 2)
        / FWHM ** 2
        * np.exp(-4 * np.log(2) * ((x + x0) ** 2 + (y + y0) ** 2) / FWHM ** 2)
    )


fig0, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

# Make data
X = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

true_params = (0, 0, 100, 7)

Z = doughnut(Y, X, *true_params)

# Plot the surface
ax0.matshow(Z, extent=(-10, 10, 10, -10))
ax0.set_title("Ground Truth")


def for_fitting(xdata, y0, x0, A, FWHM):
    yy, xx = xdata
    return doughnut(yy, xx, y0, x0, A, FWHM).ravel()


noisy_data = np.random.poisson(Z) + np.random.randn(*Z.shape)

ax1.matshow(noisy_data, extent=(-10, 10, 10, -10))
ax1.set_title("Noisy Data")

opt_params, cov = curve_fit(for_fitting, (Y, X), noisy_data.ravel(), p0=(0, 0, 10, 1))

print(opt_params)

fit_Z = doughnut(Y, X, *opt_params)

ax2.matshow(fit_Z, extent=(-10, 10, 10, -10))
ax2.set_title("Fit")

fig0.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Its the ordering that NumPy uses and the one that I've become comfortable with. It doesn't change anything, but if you like the other ordering then you'll need make sure you change it everywhere else too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very instructive answer, many good details... :)  I also like the `for_fitting` function, it's much cleaner than butchering the fit function definition. Just one question, why did you change the argument order of `X` and `Y` in the fit function definition? Is it because in image files, width (x-axis) comes first before height (y-axis), while in NumPy arrays, rows (y-axis) come before columns (x-axis)?

Comment: Whoops, just had to do an edit... Okay, thanks a lot!!

Comment: By the way, how do call what is happening inside `for_fitting`? It looks very much like variable packing/unpacking, but you're using `yy, xx = xdata` instead of `*args`. Is this equivalent to `(yy, xx) = xdata`?

Comment: Yes they’re the same, I’m not sure if brackets are recommended for a single line. I’d encourage you (and everyone else) to use a code formatter. I use [black](https://github.com/psf/black). You can set up text editors like VS code and SublimeText to run it whenever you save a file.

Comment: Nice, I'll try it. Thanks!